# apply() function invoked on Function.prototype.bind in javascript?

Tags: javascript, apply

I am reading Javascript book 'Speaking Javascript'. In an example the author is simulating the apply function for the Date constructor.

```
new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(Date, [null,2011,11,24]))
```

The statement is very confusing and when i try figure out i get confused by the presence of null and that too inside the array. Can anyone help me by explaining the internals of this statement.

Comment: `bind.apply` O.o

Comment: This looks like a contrived example. I don't think you will every find something like this in production code. Maybe ask on code golf: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes i am sure that this will not be in production but just to deepen my understanding i want to know what is it because this code is working fine. So there would be a reason behind it for sure.

Comment: `bind.apply` is an excellent way to "impress" future maintainer with your functional programming kung fu. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unroll expression step by step

```
Function.prototype.bind.apply(Date, [null,2011,11,24])
```

This expression `apply`'s `bind` function using `Date` as context (`this`) with arguments list `[null,2011,11,24]`

First `Function.prototype.bind` is just a way to access `bind` method every function inherits from its prototype. One could use any other function to get it. For example `var bind = (function(){}).bind` or even `var bind = Date.bind`

Then `fn.apply(ctx, [arg1, ..., argN])` calls `fn` in context of `ctx` with given arguments  is `ctx::fn(arg1, ..., argN)` (where `::` is [bind operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bind-operator))

Then `fn.bind(ctx, arg1, ..., argN)` is roughly equivalent to creating a new function with bounded context and partially applied arguments

```
function(moreArg1, ..., moreArgN) {
   return fn.apply(ctx, [arg1, ..., argN, moreArg1, ..., moreArgN])
}
```

So `bind.apply(fn, [ctx, arg1, ..., argN])` is "same" as `fn.bind(ctx, arg1, ..., argN)`

Combining both gives

```
Date.bind(null,2011,11,24)
```

Answer (score 1):

Soooo, I am in no means an expert, but let me take a crack at it, but let's begin at the end:

The array are arguments which are passed to the `Date` constructor. You can also use the `call` method, in this case, you don't use an array, but just put the arguments:

```
new (Function.prototype.bind.call(Date, null, 2011, 11, 24));
```

Now it gets more confusing, we got `apply` on a `bind`.

`apply` as we know, calls the function it's applied to. In this case `bind`. The first argument is the `this` property and sets the context for the `call`. In this case `Date`. The rest of the arguments gets passed to the `bind` method. The `bind` method gets called like this:

```
.bind(null, 2011, 11, 24);
```

The `this` arguments is null, and is ignored. `bind` as you know, returns a callable function. This callable function is the function on which `bind` is called on. In this case `Function.prototype`. Which is the prototype of the constructor of `Function`....

Ahhh, so now we have a constructor, with the `this` context set to `Date`, and where the parameters for the constructor are always: `2011`, `11`, `24`.

```
new (Date.bind(null,2011,11,24));
```

You can call the constructor using the `new` keyword, which creates an instance of `Date` where the year is 2011, the month is December (because January is 0), and the day is the 24th..